# Azure App Service : exec: \"./start.sh\": stat ./start.sh: no such file or directory: unknown (Docker)

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

While trying to push the Docker file changes onto ACR I am getting the following error in App Service Azure :

`ERROR - Container start failed for clickpost-testing_0_8217683a with System.AggregateException, One or more errors occurred. (Docker API responded with status code=BadRequest, response={"message":"OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: \"./start.sh\": stat ./start.sh: no such file or directory: unknown"} ) (Docker API responded with status code=BadRequest, response={"message":"OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: \"./start.sh\": stat ./start.sh: no such file or directory: unknown"} ) InnerException: Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException, Docker API responded with status code=BadRequest, response={"message":"OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: \"./start.sh\": stat ./start.sh: no such file or directory: unknown"}`

What could be the possible reason for the same.

Comment: The file isn't in the container at all; it has DOS line endings; its "shebang" line names an interpreter that doesn't exist (maybe you've labeled a shell script as requiring GNU bash but you're running it in an Alpine image without bash); ...  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: Try using dos2unix to update the line endings. Re-build the image and test. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dos2unix-unix2dos-commands/